# Items desordenados Android Studio 2.3

Tags: java, android, android-studio

¿alguien sabe porque los objetos salen desordenados? cuando ejecutó la aplicación en el emulador, los objetos se muestran desordenados en la aplicación y no como se muestran en la interfaz de desarrollo. :( 
 Esto ocurrió después de que el android studio se actualizo hace unos días. Les agradacería mucho su ayuda!.

[image: Interfaz de desarrollo]

[image: Aplicación en Emulador]

XML

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="193dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Ingresa el primer numero"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="36dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Ingresa el segundo numero"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="104dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.052" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Resultado"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="168dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="293dp" />
```

Comment: Por favor, pon el codigo de tu XML, me suena a que es un constraint layout sin constraint con lo cual todo se desordena al ejecutar pero no en la vista diseño.

Comment: Hola, actualice mi comentario y puse mi codigo XML, esta es su cabecera de mi codigo :

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="isaias.isgb.codigo.actualizacion.com.spinner.MainActivity">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

es justamente lo que yo te decia.

Fijate en este fragmento de tu codigo:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="193dp" />
```

Como ves no tiene ninguna constraint y tus controles se posicionan globalmente en la esquina de arriba a la izquierda. Lee esta pagina y veras como logras hacer lo que quieres:

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/layout-editor.html?hl=es-419

Si tienes mas dudas pregunta por aqui pero creo que leyendo eso podras.

Comment: Muchas gracias! ya pude solucionar el problema!

Answer (score 0):

Es por los constraint, un modo rapido de resolverlo es dando click derecho sobre el item --> constraint layout --> Infer Constraints

Fijate si así se entiendo lo que quiero decir

[image: .]

Comment: ¿podrías agregar un poco más de detalles o explicaciones a tu respuesta? Gracias.

Answer (score -1):

Todo ese código que ha puesto en el xml debería estar enmarcado o incluido en un LinearLayout o en un RelativeLayout. En el primero debe usar android:orientation="vertical" para que se alineen unos debajo de otros. Con el RelativeLayout tiene más flexibilidad a la hora de ordenar los componentes del frame. Busque información en https://developer.android.com acerca de los layouts.